# Convert Encoded GUID to String Format

Tags: sqlite, ascii, guid

I am querying a Sqlite3 database which stores GUID's using Javascript. But I am unable to convert the encoded values into known GUID values.

The values in their raw format appears as '�ո�+�A�I9��W' when viewed as a string value. But I know the true value should be 'ddb8d5b7-182b-419c-a449-1d391fb18757'.

I don't know where to begin in identifying the appropriate encoding.

Many thanks
James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [blog post](https://neosmart.net/blog/2018/converting-a-binary-blob-guid-to-text-in-sql/) by Mahmoud Al-Qudsi, the conversion from a 16 byte BLOB representation of a UUID in Sqlite to a string representation is like this:

```
SELECT
  substr(hguid, 7, 2) || substr(hguid, 5, 2) 
  || substr(hguid, 3, 2) || substr(hguid, 1, 2) || '-'
  || substr(hguid, 11, 2) || substr(hguid, 9, 2) || '-'
  || substr(hguid, 15, 2) || substr(hguid, 13, 2) || '-'
  || substr(hguid, 17, 4) || '-'
  || substr(hguid, 21, 12)

AS guid

FROM (SELECT hex(guid) AS hguid FROM messages)
```